# React Native Flex Items Alignment

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I need to arrange three items in row one on the leftmost and two others in the center. How I can achieve that?

[image]

I have already tried the following:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
<View style={{flexDirect: 'row', justiftContent:'flex-start'}}>
<Text>item1</Text>
</View>

<View>
<Image source={calendar} style={{height: 30, width:30}} />
</View>

<View>
<Text>item2</Text>
</View>
</View>
```

but this code center aligns all the items, I get something like this:

```
     ------------------------------|
    |      item1,image,item2       |
    |                              |
    |______________________________|
```

I have tried space-between as well, but it aligns item2 on the rightmost side.

```
     ------------------------------   
    |item1,      image,      item2 |
    |                              |
    |______________________________|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following, I provide you a solution to your problem. Btw you have several typos in your style definitions.

**Code:**

```
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 20}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
    <Text>item1</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <Image source={{uri: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MPV2METPeJU/maxresdefault.jpg'}} style={{height: 30, width:30}} />
    <Text>item2</Text>
  </View>
   <View style={{flex: 1}} />
  </View>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Working example:**

https://snack.expo.io/H1Zv59D6r

Comment: Sorry about that I wrote the code directly in the editor. applying style flex:1 to a single View actually disturbs other Views on the same screen. Otherwise, your solution works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent:'space-between',width:"50%"}}>
        <View >
        <Text>item1</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
        <Image source={calendar} style={{height: 30, width:30}} />
        </View>
    </View>

    <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:"flex-start",width:"50%"}}>
    <Text>item2</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```